# Nexenta (solaris) недоступность некоторых хостов в сети

Tags: ping, nexenta, solaris, сеть

Добрый день,

Помогите разобраться, баг это или фича )) Я не могу понять в какую сторону рыть.

Есть сервер, на нем в качестве ОС - nexenta (почти клон Open Solaris). Проблема такая, что он не видит некоторые хосты и его не видно этим же хостам. Закономерности никакой.

Проявляется как невозможность даже пропинговать, либо как-то иначе обратиться к машине (telnet\ssh\чтоугодно\разные_сетевые_протоколы)

Нигде нет никаких файерволов и прочих заграждений. Сетевые настройки машин практически идентичные (одна и та же подсеть, статические адреса, mtu у всех одно)

пингуем nexentу с проблемной машины

```
-bash-3.2$ ping nexentaPING nexenta.geo (192.168.1.39) 56(84) bytes of data.From ory.geo (192.168.1.2) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host UnreachableFrom ory.geo (192.168.1.2) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

наоборот

```
root@nexenta:/volumes# ping oryno answer from 192.168.1.2
```

tcpdumpом, вижу что пакеты между хостами ходят, но результата мало

попробовал просмотреть на nexenta с помощью truss (аналог strace в linux)что делает процесс ping 192.168.1.2

вот дамп http://pastebin.com/Y5YHWPDF

и вот дамп пинга другой машины где все ок http://pastebin.com/FjqzN9my

Это баг или фича solaris ?

p.s. netstat -nr, ifconfig

**nexenta**

```
root@nexenta:/volumes/RZ2/BAZA# ifconfig -alo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000bond0: flags=1001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,FIXEDMTU> mtu 1500 index 2        inet 192.168.1.39 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255        ether b4:99:ba:5c:15:5lo0: flags=2002000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv6,VIRTUAL> mtu 8252 index 1        inet6 ::1/128root@nexenta:/volumes/RZ2/BAZA# netstat -nrRouting Table: IPv4  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------default              192.168.1.3          UG        2       7688127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH       55     685779 lo0192.168.1.0          192.168.1.39         U        29   98069868 bond0Routing Table: IPv6  Destination/Mask            Gateway                   Flags Ref   Use    If--------------------------- --------------------------- ----- --- ------- -----::1                         ::1                         UH      2    2568 lo0
```

**ory**

```
[root@ory]# netstat -nrKernel IP routing tableDestination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth00.0.0.0         192.168.1.3     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0[root@ory]# ifconfigeth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:87:00:07          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe87:7/64 Scope:Link          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          RX packets:17761426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:8332937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000          RX bytes:2551067123 (2.3 GiB)  TX bytes:4382075369 (4.0 GiB)          Interrupt:51 Base address:0x2024lo        Link encap:Local Loopback          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1          RX packets:4066546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:4066546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0          RX bytes:973066970 (927.9 MiB)  TX bytes:973066970 (927.9 MiB)virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0          inet6 addr: fe80::200:ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:1303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:60962 (59.5 KiB)
```

Comment: у проблемной машины какие    ifconfigи    netstat -nrда и у остальных тоже надо посмотреть

Comment: "tcpdumpом, вижу что пакеты между хостами ходят, но результата мало" я правда в этом сомневаюсь видя "From ory.geo (192.168.1.2) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable", проверьте еще таблицу маршрутизации и arp таблицу.

Comment: @ArcherGodsonдобавил данные в сам вопрос.@pyatakкстати, да     [root@ory]# arp -a | grep 192.168.1.39    nexenta.geo (192.168.1.39) at <incomplete> on eth0в то время как в arp таблице на nexenta вообще нет упоминаний об хосте oraи с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Хм, интересно, а попробуйте руками mac адрес прописать там и там...Явно проблема в канальном уровне, осталось понять где именно. Держите в курсе.

Comment: @pyatakдобавил и туда и туда, связь пошла.отчего mac так просто не передается - непонятно

Comment: Мне тоже так сложно ответить почему...Но интересно.

Comment: а что между хостами по L2? почему один bond, почему второй virbr?

Comment: @ArcherGodsonда какая разница какие названия)) назвал bond, а мог назвать интерфейс hren100, а virbr на той машине использовался для опр. задач и сейчас не нуженю.Это не причина проблем.

Comment: > а что между хостами по L2?

Comment: ProCurve J8693A Switch 3500yl-48GProCurve J4904A Switch 2848@ArcherGodson

Comment: А там на этих свитчах не могут намеренно резаться широковещательные arp-запросы? потому как arp who-has является единственным в данной проблеме L2-широковещательным.